# My if statement at the bottom of my code is not printing in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The last five or so lines of my code have an if statement and that doesn't print in my code.
I tried to change the numbers, and add new conditions, however, it still does not print. I even tried to remove the rounding for the if statement and it still does not print. I'm confused as to why the if statement at the bottom does not print.

Comment: If you're just pasting this into interactive, it loses track of the indents as you have blank lines. If not, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your logic in the if elif statements is the same...

change one.

Edit:
RoundedExpectedReturnE > ARE  ==  ARE < RoundedExpectedReturnE:

Comment: Worked! I completely missed that! Thanks so much!